# How to print values from array being 2 Row per page in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, printing, datagridview

Hi guys here I'm again!

my question is how to print a sequencial number from an array in the same document being the max of sequencial number per page is 2

the main scenary works on to print only the checked rows in a datagridview!
when i check the row it's added to array  and so to print, but i need to take the FIRST and  SECOND value in the array and print too in the same page  ,EVEN the checked rows is more than two. if I have 6  checked rows ,then the print will print in 3 pages

MY DATAGRIDVIEW

```
checked row = value1
checked row = value2
unchecked row = value3
unchecked row = value4
checked row = value5
unchecked row = value6
unchecked row = value7
checked row = value8
unchecked row = value9
checked row = value10
checked row = value11



Exemple: in the array contains= value1,value2, value5,value8         value10,value11

Document 1 
Page 1
______________________
Value 1       Value 2
______________________
Document 1
Page 2
______________________
Value 5       Value 8
______________________
Document 1
Page 3
______________________
Value 10       Value 11
```

---

thnaks in advance guys ,be free to format this question as needed!

Comment: You can use this answer to print 2 label in each pages, Pay attention to `d` in codes that is width of label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using IDAutomation.NetAssembly;  

    private int currentPrintingIndex = 0;       

    List<string> CheckedValues = new List<string>();

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,       System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
     Font fbarra = new Font("IDAutomationSC128S", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

 IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> CheckedValues =    this.dgv1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
        .Skip(currentPrintingIndex);

      IEnumerator<DataGridViewRow> cve = CheckedValues.GetEnumerator();
      int count = 0;
      int pos = 60;

      while ((e.HasMorePages = cve.MoveNext()) && count++ < 2)
      {
       var cellValues = cve.Current.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Skip(1)    //instead of .Where(cell => cell.ColumnIndex > 0)
                    .Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString())
                    .ToArray();



       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       builder.Append(string.Join(",", cellValues));

       string fullline = builder.ToString();
       string[] column1 = fullline.Split(',');


          var cents = column1[3].Substring(0, 2);
          var descr = column1[1].ToString();

          var descr2 = descr.Substring(0, 30);
          var descr3 = descr.Substring(30);

          var encodeddata1 = Encode.Code128(column1[0].ToString(), 0, false);
          var number = encodeddata1;

 e.Graphics.DrawString(number, fbarra, Brushes.Black, pos, 105);//Barcode

 currentPrintingIndex += 1;

 pos += 150;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that do what you need with a `List<string>` you can simply use `List<DataGridViewRow>` instead of `List<string>`:

```
List<string> CheckedValues = new List<string>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckedValues = new List<string> { "value1", "value2", "value5", "value8", "value10", "value11" };
    printDocument1.Print();
}

int currentPrintingIndex = 0;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Width of output labels
    var d= this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width / 2;

    //Print first output label
    if (CheckedValues.Count > currentPrintingIndex)
    {
        var currentValue = CheckedValues[currentPrintingIndex];
        e.Graphics.DrawString(currentValue.ToString(),
                    this.Font,
                    new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),
                    new RectangleF(
                        0,
                        0,
                        d,
                        this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

        currentPrintingIndex += 1;
    }

    //Print second output label
    if (CheckedValues.Count > currentPrintingIndex)
    {
        var currentValue = CheckedValues[currentPrintingIndex];
        e.Graphics.DrawString(currentValue.ToString(),
                    this.Font,
                    new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor),
                    new RectangleF(
                        d,
                        0,
                        d,
                        this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

        currentPrintingIndex += 1;
    }

    //If there is more item to print, go to next page
    e.HasMorePages = CheckedValues.Count > currentPrintingIndex;
}
```

And the output will be:

```
Page 1
value 1                                    value 2

Page 2
value 5                                    value 8

Page 3
value 10                                   value 11
```

The logic behind this is very simple. We want to show data in 2 output columns. So we should check if we are not at the end of Checked Cells List, print first row, and then again check if we are not at the end of Checked Cells List print seccond row then check if there are more items in checked cells List, so we say go to next page using `e.HasMorePages = CheckedValues.Count > currentPrintingIndex;` and move the print pointer to next checked cell.

### EDIT

---

And here is the ultimate solution edited by Elton Joani

```
private int currentPrintingIndex = 0;       
List<string> CheckedValues = new List<string>();

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Barcode Font
    Font fbarra = new Font("IDAutomationSC128S", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> CheckedValues = this.dgv1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
    .Skip(currentPrintingIndex);

    IEnumerator<DataGridViewRow> cve = CheckedValues.GetEnumerator();
    int count = 0;
    int pos = 60;

    while ((e.HasMorePages = cve.MoveNext()) && count++ < 2)
    {
        var cellValues = cve.Current.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Skip(1)    //instead of .Where(cell => cell.ColumnIndex > 0)
                    .Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString())
                    .ToArray();


        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(string.Join(",", cellValues));

        string fullline = builder.ToString();
        string[] column1 = fullline.Split(',');

        var cents = column1[3].Substring(0, 2);
        var descr = column1[1].ToString();
        var descr2 = descr.Substring(0, 30);
        var descr3 = descr.Substring(30);

        var encodeddata1 = Encode.Code128(column1[0].ToString(), 0, false);
        var number = encodeddata1;

        //draw barcode
        e.Graphics.DrawString(number, fbarra, Brushes.Black, pos, 105);
        currentPrintingIndex += 1;

        pos += 150;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei ! I tryed so many time to adapt this code to mine . but I couldn't figure out how to do it keeping with the same idea once the values comes from datagridview and after I send to 1 array in this case I need do it for each 2 checked Rows  and create an array for the first and Other Array to the Second

Comment: @EltonJoani First, you should use exactly this sample code to learn about logic behind the answer. Then you can simply convert it to your specific case.

Comment: @EltonJoani while the post provided here answers the question, I am waiting to hear good news from you. I Updated the answer to add some description at the end of answer.

Comment: hi Reza Aghaei , I did exactly you told me, copied and tried to learn about this code , and I got it partially , except where the code is (CheckedValues = new List<string> { "value1", "value2", "value5", "value8", "value10", "value11" };).....I tried to set an new array to replace this values but  i didn't succeed!  the rest I got to know how that works!

Comment: @EltonJoani  Instead of this `List<string>` you can simply use list of checked rows.

Comment: Reza  Aghaei I tried out another way and I successed! your sample was helpful for me!!!

Comment: @EltonJoani Happy to hear that you solved the problem and thank you for up vote.

Comment: @EltonJoani It seems you have got the main Idea and it is so good, would you like to edit the main answer and add your codes below the main answer? I think it will be useful to have a general answer this way:)

Comment: @EltonJoani its your choice and feel free to do what you prefer :) +1 for your answer ;)

Comment: I would  like you to  edit the main answer for me! there's some editing rules I don't know yet! anyway ! thanks for all your support and  share your ideas and Knowledge! Stay fine and best regards!!!

Comment: @EltonJoani I edited the main answer for you and added an edit part and metioned edited by Elton Joani